# How to close a child modal without closing its parent when using Tailwind in React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a modal component which has a button to open a child modal window. The problem is, when I close the child modal, the parent modal also closes. I would like to be able to only close the child modal when I click its close button. I am using Tailwind and HeadlessUI (https://headlessui.dev/) for the modals.

Here is a codesandbox, and the code is also below: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-jackson-3du6v

I am using differently named close functions, and differently named props.

index.js

```
export default function Home() {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-gray-200">
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} className="font-bold">open modal</button>
            <ParentModal isOpen={isOpen} setIsOpen={setIsOpen}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

parent modal

```
const ParentModal = ({ isOpen, setIsOpen }) => {

    const [childIsOpen, setChildIsOpen] = useState(false)

    function closeModal() {
        setIsOpen(false);
    }

    return (
        <>
        <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment}>
            <Dialog as="div" className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto" onClose={closeModal}>
        ...
            </Dialog>
        </Transition>
        <ChildModal isChildOpen={childIsOpen} setIsChildOpen={setChildIsOpen} />
        </>
    )
}
```

child modal

```
const ChildModal = ({ isChildOpen, setIsChildOpen }) => {

    function closeChildModal() {
        setIsChildOpen(false);
    }

    return (
        <Transition appear show={isChildOpen} as={Fragment}>
            <Dialog as="div" className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto" onClose={closeChildModal}>
            ...
            </Dialog>
        </Transition>
    )
}
```

Many thanks, Matt

Comment: The parent modal is closing, as soon as you clicked on child modal or click outside of the modal content, since that triggers the `onClose` method of the Dialog. To keep the parent modal open, you can manually control the `onClose` prop of the parent dialog. Original [post](https://githubmemory.com/repo/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/621)

Comment: Great, thank you Junaid. That works. I used 'static' and changed the onClose method of the parent. Happy to mark it correct if you want.

Comment: That's great...